# How do I print hex values stored in little endian?

Tags: c, printf

I seem to have got myself in a mess over Endianess. My machine is a 64-bit machine with a Ryzen 3 processor. Reports as little endian.

I'm writing a little program in C that traverses a processes virtual memory and parses MSDOS headers and checks for MZ in the header signature.

Taken from my code:

```
int pid = 10964;
DWORD_PTR addr = 0x7FF7BD730000;
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64 mbi;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS header;

HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
if (pHandle == NULL)
{
    printf("Error getting handle for process %i. Failed with error: %i", pid, GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

/*
 * Retrieve information on virtual address space
 */
BOOL vqeResult = VirtualQueryEx(pHandle, addr, &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64));
if (!vqeResult)
{
    printf("Error querying virtual memory: %i", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

PrintMemoryBasicInformation64(&mbi);

/*
 * Read the DOS header
 */
BOOL rpmResult = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)mbi.BaseAddress, (LPVOID)&header, sizeof(header), 0);
if (!rpmResult) {
    printf("Error reading memory address: %i. Failed with error: %i", mbi.BaseAddress, GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
```

All works well, except when I try to print the signature:

```
printf("Signature: %x", header.Signature);
```

It gives an incorrect hex value that is basially `MZ` in reverse:

```
Signature: 0x785a4d
```

As my system is little endian this makes sense but how would I go about printing this correctly?

I've attached an image to show the value stored in `headers.Signature`:

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, 7887437 (base 10) *is* 785a4d in hex. Did you expect 0xd4a587?

Comment: @Bob__ yes, which is `xZM`. It should be `MZ`. docs say signature is 4 bytes, 2 of which are null https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_image_nt_headers ... I'm getting confused somewhere.

Comment: Endianness concerns how the number is stored in memory, but C in itself is dealing with the number itself, so printing, shifting, etc happens the same way regardless of endianness. Now, if you read binary data directly into an integer type (larger than `char`), then endianness should match, but since you are reading little-endian data on a little-endian machine, I fail to see the relevance of endianness here.

Comment: @Arkku Apologies if it's not an endian issue and is titled incorrectly. I guess I'll delete and find out what problem I'm dealing with before posting my question. I've still got my training wheels on. Any pointers on where I may be going wrong?

Comment: @Bob__ sorry missed the edit. Yes, that's the value I am expecting.

Comment: This works fine for me, producing 'MZ':   `int sig = 0x785a4d;
    printf("Signature: %c%c\n", ((char*)&sig)[0], ((char*)&sig)[1]);`

Comment: BTW, you should use `%lx` as it seems that it's an `unsigned long`.

Comment: It is unclear what `ReadProcessMemory` does. Perhaps it is expecting the `header` parameter to be zero filled?

Comment: @jxh There's no mention of such requirements in the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks folks. I solved it in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

@Arkuu was correct, this wasn't an endian issue.

**Update**

I wasn't happy with the solution below. I felt like there was something more to this that I was missing. I should have been using `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` instead of `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` as I was inspecting a DOS stub and not a PE header.

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER header;
...
printf("Signature: %#x\n", header.e_magic);
```

---

<del>The way I solved it was to use [_byteswap_ulong][1] like so:

    #include 
    ...
    printf("Signature: %#lx\n", _byteswap_ulong(header.Signature));

This macro will reverse the order of bytes.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_image_nt_headers) the signature is:

    A 4-byte signature identifying the file as a PE image. The bytes are "PE\0\0".

On a little endian system this would be in reverse order, as is what happened to in my case. Using the `_byteswap_ulong` macro reverses the bytes and returns the value I expected.</del>